# Composer not pulling in the right dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

Take a look at [this `composer.json` snippet](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Intl/blob/cee74d08590d66b1725ad0600f0af32df0df2f06/composer.json) :

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "illuminate/container": ">=5.0,<5.7",
        "commerceguys/intl": "^0.7.3",
        "jenssegers/date": ">=3.2.3,< 4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "orchestra/testbench": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    }
}
```

[`orchestra/testbench` requires `laravel/framework`](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench/blob/750a62bfb3431b6398c94dbf20a152ce43dc8772/composer.json#L21), and [`laravel/framework` replaces all `illuminate/*` packages](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5caa88acde3d8a82fcbb9bbec8dde45dc49d4b7b/composer.json#L49).

Now in my Travis builds there's something weird going on. For builds where I just run the tests in PHP 7.0 without any environment variables, I'd expect `laravel/framework 5.x` to be installed as it should replace `illuminate/container` and this one's version was constrained.

Yet, `illuminate/container` is installed separately and `laravel/framework 4.2` is installed?!

The Travis builds of [another package of mine](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone) using similar setup is performing just fine... The Illuminate package is NOT installed separately and `laravel/framework` is constrained by illuminate's version.

I'm quite clueless. I'd appreciate any help!

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/Propaganistas/Laravel-Intl/builds/341337463)'s the failing Travis build.

Comment: Which PHP version is used to run `composer`?

Comment: PHP 7.x (see [Travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/Propaganistas/Laravel-Intl/builds/341337463))